# Android Filter multiple columns in TableView

Tags: android, kotlin, tableview

I have implemented the TableView from https://github.com/evrencoskun/TableView.

But i'm having some doubts about how to make my filter String with multiple columns filtering.

I have a table with name, middle name, and last name, among other columns. 
I need to filter my table with those fields.

The documentation marks

> Multiple filtering combinations are supported such as COLUMN + WHOLE TABLE filter or MULTIPLE COLUMNS filter: e.g. "Happy" + "Boy" + all strings with a '-' character.

but when i tried it does not work

```
override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
    val filter = et_first_name.text.toString() + '-' + et_middle_name.text.toString() + '-' + s.toString()
    filterTable(filter)
}
```

```
private fun filterTable(filter: String) {
    tableFilter.set(filter)
}
```

My filter val ends up like `Jorge-Margarito-Martinez`

but it returns an empty list, whit an empty table